# How to handle JS calls to methods involving jQuery outside of document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a small architectural problem for a project I'm working on. Basically I've split all the Javascript logic in various files, one of them being `interface.js`. Inside this file I have a lot of jQuery code inside `$(document).ready()` but I also have a few functions that need to be called from other JS files, such as:

```
function hideProgressBar() {
    $('.progress').hide();
}
```

I have declared these functions after `$(document).ready()` hoping that jQuery would be loaded by the time they're executed, and in practice that actually seems to work. Is there a better way of doing this though? What are the risks?

Comment: If they are only called *after* the DOM is ready (e.g. from code that is only run after the DOM is ready) it's absolutely fine.

Comment: jQuery will be already loaded. ready has nothing to do with jQuery being ready. Read the documentation!

Comment: when the page is ready, the jquery will be "ready" too, of course. the readiness of the page and the one of jquery, are slight different.

Comment: @lonesomeday can the DOM be considered ready when the user sees the  page?

Comment: @mm2703 Not necessarily. How is this function being called?

Comment: This specific function is called by myself after `window.onload`, which from what I've just read is fired after `document.ready`, so this is good. However I'd like to call another of these "outsider" functions when the user clicks on an link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call document.ready inside your function.

```
function hideProgressBar() {
    $(function(){
        $('.progress').hide();
    });
}
```

You can also declare all your functions inside one large document.ready call.

```
$(function(){
    window.hideProgressBar = function () {
        $('.progress').hide();
    };
});
```

Normally, however, these type of functions are events or called by jquery event which means that the document is already ready.

Comment: What happens if the first function you've mentioned is called and `document` is not ready? Will the script wait and try again a few milliseconds afterwards, or do I have to write code to register the click and try to launch it later myself?

Comment: In the first example, when the function gets invoked, the body gets queued into the document.ready event and waits until it gets fired.  you won't have to worry about firing it separately yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try make it in pure js.

```
var array_el = document.getElementsByClassName('progress');
if (array_el)
{
    var needed_el = array_el[0];
    needed_el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: no, i like it. In fact, i like it more than YUI, but i tried to come up with some answer.